# How to find defining ideal of an affine variety?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, math-software

Consider the subvariety $V$ of $\mathbb{C}^{16} \times \mathbb{C}^{16}$ given by
\begin{align*}
V = \{ (X, Y) \in \mathbb{C}^{16} \times \mathbb{C}^{16}: X = \left( \begin {array}{cccc} 0&0&-\mu_{{3,4}}&\mu_{{1,4}}
\\ 0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&-{\frac {{\mu_{{3,4
}}}^{2}}{\mu_{{1,4}}}}&\mu_{{3,4}}\\ 0&0&0&0\end {array}
 \right) ,  Y = \left( \begin {array}{cccc} 0&\nu_{{1,2}}&0&\nu_{{1,4}}
\\ 0&{\frac { \left( p\mu_{{1,4}}\nu_{{1,2}}-q\mu_{{1,4}}\nu_{{1,2}}-q\mu_{{3,4}}\nu_{{1,4}} \right) \mu_{{3,4}}}{{\mu_{{1,4}}}^{2}p}}&0&{
\frac {p\mu_{{3,4}}\nu_{{1,4}}+q\mu_{{1,4}}\nu_{{1,2}}+q\mu_{{3,4}}\nu_{{1,4}}}{pX
_{{1,4}}}}\\ 0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0
\end {array} \right), \mu_{ij}, \nu_{ij} \in \mathbb{C} \}.
\end{align*}

I would like to find the defining ideal of $V$, i.e. to find $I$ in $\mathbb{C}[V]=\mathbb{C}[X_{13}, X_{14}, X_{33},X_{34}, Y_{12}, Y_{14}, Y_{22}, Y_{24}]/I$. I found some relations satified by $X_{ij}, Y_{ij}$:
\begin{align}
& X_{1,3}^2+X_{1,4} X_{3,3}=0 \\
& (p^2+q^2)Y_{1,2} Y_{2,4} -(p+q)^2 Y_{1,4} Y_{2,2}-p q(Y_{1,2}^2+Y_{2,4}^2)=0.
\end{align}
But maybe there are some more relations. How could I find all the relations? How to do this in Maple or Macaulay2 or some other math software? The ground field $\mathbb{C}$ can also be changed to $\mathbb{Q}$. Thank you very much.

Comment: why do you need those zero coefficiens? I think the problem looks better if you write two vector in $C^4$

Comment: @ali, thank you very much for your suggestions. Yes, we can change it to two vectors in $\mathbb{C}^{4}$ as you suggested. In other examples, we need $\mathbb{C}^{16} \times \mathbb{C}^{16}$.

Comment: also you don't need  $X_{3,3}$ at all. the first equation is not really enough so it is better to remove $X_(3,3)$ .also you don't need $Y_{2,2},Y_{2,4}$. your ring is just $\mathbb{C}[x_1,x_2,x_3,y_1,y_2]_{x_1,x_2}$(it means that $x_1,x_2$ are invertible)there is no other relation between these variable. if you really need other variable just add them and put the value of them in the $I$. for example $-X_4X_2=X_1^2$

Comment: @ali, thanks a lot!